# SQL: How to create view with a list of tables with unspecified length?

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have a list of tables: t1,...,tn;

Now I want to create a view that combines all of these tables. I have figured out how to do that if I know exactly what tables I need to use (eg, t1,...,t5). However, the number of such tables will change in real time and so I need to create a view that accommodates that real time.

Note: having tables organized as mentioned initially is unavoidable, so I need to look into a solution that works around that.

I thought of creating a synonym that i can change real time but then how do I write the SQL for the view that iterates through that list"

Thanks for your time!

Comment: At least the tables have names based on a rule? They really are named `t1`, `t2` etc. ?

Comment: they follow a naming convention ... <standard string>_num. So yea they are called t1, t2, t3... where t is a constant string.

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the view on add/delete such a table?

Comment: @StanislavL I didn't understand your question.

Comment: The tables somewhere are created/deleted. Could you recreate the view when such a table is created/deleted?

Comment: No. Right now all names are hard coded in the code for generating view. Maybe a better way to phrase my question is that is it possible to create a view by passing a number N and then a view is created by combining tables t_1 ... t_n?